# Drupal- after moving installed module from modules directory to contrib, modules is not on the list

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-modules

After installing and enabling module [adminstration menu](https://www.drupal.org/project/admin_menu) with update manager, I have moved the installed module to the contrib directory of my project. 
I have also cleared the `cache` in the `administration/configuration/development/performance`.

How can I make it visible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing I'd try is to move the module back to where ever it was originally installed and then enable it, disable it and uninstall it. Uninstalling will remove any references in the system table that might be confusing Drupal.

If you don't know where it was before you moved it, you can find that info in the system table.

Then move it to the new location and it should be visible and you can enable it from there.

If that doesn't work, you should be able to use the [registry rebuild](https://www.drupal.org/project/registry_rebuild) module to clear out any remnants the old version. Backup your database first.